# SQL Connection works on main thread but fails on BackgroundWorker thread!

Tags: sql-server

I have a strange problem. The SQL server data access works fine in the main thread but fails if i call the same from a background worker thread. Please help. I dint find anything on the net except i that suspect HostProtectionAttribute of BackgroundWorker.

When i try to open the connection on the background thread i get the following error :
"A transport-level error has occurred when sending the request to the server. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket.)"

I think the connection is being refused as soon as the request is made. But the same works on the GUI thread. Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you give a code example?  Background threads can connect to SQL Server just as easily as any other thread (the distinction is relative).